Crypto Noob. Did I mess up?
Yesterday I attempted to send crypto from a Metamask wallet to my Paypal wallet. Here is the step by steps I took...

I opened up my wallet on Metamask that had ETH on it.
I clicked send ETH to outside wallet
I opened up my Paypal wallet and clicked the receive ETH button which opened up a QR code to scan/ETH Wallet Address.
I scanned the QR to send the ETH.
I clicked send. The issue is the ETH never showed up in my paypal wallet.

I started investigating what I did wrong and figured out the issue. My ETH on metamask was on the Base network. I am assuming the ETH address on my paypal wallet is ERC-20? So basically I believe the networks aren't compatible?
Looking further into it, the ETH wallet that the funds were sent to does not match the wallet address on my paypal account (even though I scanned the QR code).
Do I have any hope?
Any suggestions appreciated.

Since the Paypal wallet is custodial (you don't have the private key right?), then you need to ask customer support for help.

Looking further into it, the ETH wallet that the funds were sent to does not match the wallet address on my paypal account (even though I scanned the QR code).

This is weird. Have you checked also on https://basescan.org/ ? I would expect to see the ETH you sent still in the same wallet. Also is that wallet empty beside your transaction, or was it used before? Try to figure out if you sent ETH to some of your contacts.
